# VSTS report on Source Control

Tags: tfs, version-control

Is there a way in VSTS 2008 to generate a report on the source control in Team Foundation Server, of what are the files that were changed by user: x for last few days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need a webpage hosted by SQL Reporting Services, or will any reporting mechanism do?  Here's a quick & dirty one:

```
tfhistory $/project -r -all -version D6/10/2009~ | % {
        $user = $_.owner
        $date = $_.creationdate
        $_.changes | % { $_.item } | 
        add-member noteproperty user $user -passthru |
        add-member noteproperty date $date -passthru    
    } |
    sort @{Expression="User";Ascending=$true},@{Expression="Date";Ascending=$false},@{Expression="ServerItem";Ascending=$true} |
    select user, date, serveritem |
    out-gridview
```

(requires the Powershell snapin from TFS Power Tools)